# How to utilize kafka batching for producer in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, librdkafka

I wrote a little Rust app that is sending messages to a kafka topic. Unfortunately, it is much slower than expected. It's was sending one message at a time with a latency of about 200ms. So I get out 5 messages per second.

I figured batching could help and found [this link](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/issues/59) where it's state that is batching is handled out-of-the-box, so I configured *queue.buffering.max.ms* to be *500* - hoping to enable batching. But it just increased the time between two messages being send to about 540ms.

I looked in the examples of [rust-rdkafka](https://github.com/fede1024/rust-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/simple_producer.rs) but I don't see what I'm missing.

I updated the "simple_producer" example to illustrate my issue:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use log::info;

use rdkafka::config::ClientConfig;
use rdkafka::producer::{FutureProducer, FutureRecord};
use tokio::time::Instant;

#[macro_use]
extern crate env_var;

async fn produce(brokers: &str, topic_name: &str, kafka_user: &str, kafka_password: &str) {
    let producer: &FutureProducer = &ClientConfig::new()
        .set("bootstrap.servers", brokers.to_string())
        .set("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
        .set("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
        .set("sasl.username", kafka_user.to_string())
        .set("sasl.password", kafka_password.to_string())
        .set("queue.buffering.max.ms", "500".to_string())
        .set("message.timeout.ms", "5000")
        .create()
        .expect("Producer creation error");

    // This loop is non blocking: all messages will be sent one after the other, without waiting
    // for the results.
    let futures = (0..5)
        .map(|i| async move {
            // The send operation on the topic returns a future, which will be
            // completed once the result or failure from Kafka is received.
            let delivery_status = producer
                .send(
                    FutureRecord::to(topic_name)
                        .payload(&format!("Message {}", i))
                        .key(&format!("Key {}", i)),
                    Duration::from_secs(0),
                )
                .await;

            // This will be executed when the result is received.
            info!("Delivery status for message {} received", i);
            delivery_status
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    // This loop will wait until all delivery statuses have been received.
    
    for future in futures {
        let timer = Instant::now();
        let result = future.await;
        info!("Future completed after {:?}. Result: {:?}", timer.elapsed(), result);
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    env_logger::init();
    let kafka_servers = env_var!(required "KAFKA_SERVERS");
    let kafka_user = env_var!(optional "KAFKA_USER", default: "$ConnectionString");
    let kafka_password = env_var!(required "KAFKA_PASSWORD");
    let kafka_topic = env_var!(required "KAFKA_TOPIC");

    produce(
        kafka_servers.as_str(),
        kafka_topic.as_str(),
        kafka_user.as_str(),
        kafka_password.as_str(),
    )
    .await;
}
```

Output:

```
[2022-09-26T13:53:50Z INFO  batch_test] Delivery status for message 0 received
[2022-09-26T13:53:50Z INFO  batch_test] Future completed at 922.2421ms. Result: Ok((0, 414835))
[2022-09-26T13:53:50Z INFO  batch_test] Delivery status for message 1 received
[2022-09-26T13:53:50Z INFO  batch_test] Future completed at 543.6226ms. Result: Ok((0, 414837))
[2022-09-26T13:53:51Z INFO  batch_test] Delivery status for message 2 received
[2022-09-26T13:53:51Z INFO  batch_test] Future completed at 549.2269ms. Result: Ok((0, 414838))
[2022-09-26T13:53:51Z INFO  batch_test] Delivery status for message 3 received
[2022-09-26T13:53:51Z INFO  batch_test] Future completed at 548.8964ms. Result: Ok((0, 414839))
[2022-09-26T13:53:52Z INFO  batch_test] Delivery status for message 4 received
[2022-09-26T13:53:52Z INFO  batch_test] Future completed at 538.4841ms. Result: Ok((0, 414840))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the requests are not sent when you think:

```
// This loop is non blocking: all messages will be sent one after the other, without waiting
// for the results.
let futures = (0..5)
    .map(|i| async move {
        // The send operation on the topic returns a future, which will be
        // completed once the result or failure from Kafka is received.
        let delivery_status = producer
            .send(
                FutureRecord::to(topic_name)
                    .payload(&format!("Message {}", i))
                    .key(&format!("Key {}", i)),
                Duration::from_secs(0),
            )
            .await;

        // This will be executed when the result is received.
        info!("Delivery status for message {} received", i);
        delivery_status
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

At this point, *no request has been sent yet*!

```
// This loop will wait until all delivery statuses have been received.
for future in futures {
    let timer = Instant::now();
    let result = future.await;
```

This will queue one request, wait for `queue.buffering.max.ms` in case another request is queued in the mean time (but none are), then send the request and wait for the response.

```
    info!("Future completed after {:?}. Result: {:?}", timer.elapsed(), result);
}
```

You need to spawn a task for each request so that they will be queued immediately:

```
let futures = (0..5)
    .map(|i| tokio::spawn (async move {
        // The send operation on the topic returns a future, which will be
        // completed once the result or failure from Kafka is received.
        let delivery_status = producer
            .send(
                FutureRecord::to(topic_name)
                    .payload(&format!("Message {}", i))
                    .key(&format!("Key {}", i)),
                Duration::from_secs(0),
            )
            .await;

        // This will be executed when the result is received.
        info!("Delivery status for message {} received", i);
        delivery_status
    }))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

At which point, you probably no longer need to tinker with `queue.buffering.max.ms`.